# How to open urls using addon for Thunderbird 68 in external browsers instead of built-in browser?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-webextensions

In Thunderbird 68 while developing addon using webextensions, it has been observed that `messenger.launchExternalURL` is not supported anymore, and the equivalent option in Webextensions is to use `browser.tabs.create`. But, the problem with `browser.tabs.create` is; it opens the link within Thunderbird itself as a new tab instead of opening the link in external browser (like Firefox, Safari or Chrome).

Following function opened the links in external browser in Thunderbird versions < 68:

```
      messenger.launchExternalURL(baseURL);
```

Where as the following opens the links in tab within Thunderbird itself, in Thunderbird versions >=68:

```
      var creating = browser.tabs.create({
          url:baseURL
      });
      creating.then(onCreated, onError);
```

So, requesting information on how make addon in Thunderbird 68+ to open links in external browser instead of built-in Thunderbird browser.

Comment: BrowseInTab ( https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/browseintab/?src=search ) is TB addon, it gives options/choices to open link in either external or internal browser.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to install an AddOn for this:
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/open-with/?src=search